# How to add icon to tabs

Tags: java, android, tabs

I am trying to add an icon to my tabs and it isnt working,

I tried adding

```
  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bodyicon));
```

and it still isnt working. When I run the application the tab bar just has the text and there is no icon

I outlined where my code is. If someone could figure out why it isnt working that would be great.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class Body extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnClickListener {

Button bAbs, bQuad2, bPecs;
TabHost th;
ImageView body;
final Context context = this;
StretchType pop;

// above I am defining all of the buttons and images, etc...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    // here I am saying get rid of the nav bar

    setContentView(R.layout.body);
    th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.thbodyview);
    bAbs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAbss);
    bPecs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPecss);

    bAbs.setOnClickListener(this);
    bPecs.setOnClickListener(this);

//*********************below are my tabs*******************************************

    th.setup();
    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("Front");
    specs.setContent(R.id.Front);
      specs.setIndicator("Front",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bodyicon));
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
    specs.setContent(R.id.Back);
    specs.setIndicator("Back");
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    specs.setIndicator("More...");
    th.addTab(specs);

}

 //***************************Above are my tabs *******************************

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bAbss:
        // below I am creating the alert dialogue
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.abs, null);
        // above I am setting the customview of the alert dialogue

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
        // here I am officially setting the custom layout

        // set dialog message

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Stretch Type");
        // alert dialogue title

        // create alert dialog
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        // above is creating the alert dialogue

        final Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) promptsView
                .findViewById(R.id.sSType);
        // above is initializing the spinner

        /*
         * dont need this button final Button mButton = (Button) promptsView
         * .findViewById(R.id.bSpinclose);
         */

        // reference UI elements from my_dialog_layout in similar fashion

        mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnSpinnerItemClicked());

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        break;

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public class OnSpinnerItemClicked implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        switch (pos) {
        case (1):
            Intent i = new Intent(Body.this, Practice.class);
            Body.this.startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}

}
```

Here is the xml

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/thbodyview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

           <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
            </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Front"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/llbottomtop"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvupper"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/bAbs"
                            android:text="Upper"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="5dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:background="@color/orange" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvlower"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
                            android:text="Lower"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivBody"
                        android:layout_width="210dp"
                        android:layout_height="430dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/body_front" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bPecss"
                        android:layout_width="83dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/bAbss"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bAbss"
                        android:text="Pecs" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bAbss"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="77dp"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/llbottomtop"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
                        android:text="Abs" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Back"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >


                   <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/llbottomtop"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvupper"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/bAbs"
                            android:text="Upper"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="5dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:background="@color/orange" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvlower"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
                            android:text="Lower"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivBody"
                        android:layout_width="210dp"
                        android:layout_height="430dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/body_back" />


                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>



        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Do you HAVE to use the TabHost, it is the only Android component I resent exists now there are ActionBar tabs...

Comment: can you post the xml where the tabhost is defined?

Comment: @j2emanue I added the xml

Answer (score 1):

My tip is to get access to the tab title textview and set left|top|right|bottom drawable

Example:

```
//to get first tab title as textView from tabHost
TextView tabTitle = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
//to set the icon to left of the tab title
tabTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                    getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.ic_tab_icon), null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two physical devices one 2.2 and the other 4.2.2.  on 2.2 there is no issue and the icon appears.  on 4.2.2 there is no icon.  Somethings changed in how tabs are laid out in Android.  If you really required to use a TabHost i saw you can pass in a view  as the tabindicator.  This code is kinda pseudo code as it still some adjustment in the UI in terms of layout but try this:

define a layout called tabindicator_layout.xml and put it in res/layout.  the contents of which look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:scaleType="center" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

then in your class code at runtime inflate this view and populate the image and textview with what you desire.  do this for each tab:

```
//*********************below are my tabs*******************************************

    th.setup();
    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("Front");
    specs.setContent(R.id.Front);

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.tabindicator_layout, th.getTabWidget(), false);
    ((TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Front");
    ((ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.image))
            .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    specs.setIndicator(tabIndicator);

    TabSpec specs2 = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
    specs2.setContent(R.id.Back);

    View tabIndicator2 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.tabindicator_layout, th.getTabWidget(), false);
    ((TextView) tabIndicator2.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Back");
    ((ImageView) tabIndicator2.findViewById(R.id.image))
            .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    specs2.setIndicator(tabIndicator2);

    TabSpec specs3 = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
    specs3.setContent(R.id.tab3);

    View tabIndicator3 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.tabindicator_layout, th.getTabWidget(), false);

    ((TextView) tabIndicator3.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("...More");
    ((ImageView) tabIndicator3.findViewById(R.id.image))
            .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    specs3.setIndicator(tabIndicator3);

    th.addTab(specs);
    th.addTab(specs2);
    th.addTab(specs3);
```

of course replace R.drawable.ic_launcher with whatever icon you want to show

another interesting thing that might help..i  notice if i pass in a blank for the title that the original way works but shows no title.  So you could go into photoshop and just add the title to the image and make it even better looking.  Try this way:

```
TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("Front");
    specs.setContent(R.id.Front);
      specs.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    th.addTab(specs);
```

Comment: @j23manue that second way (leaving the title blank) works thanks